# Calling method with array index

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have this exercise:

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main (String [] args){
        int index=1;
        getArray()[index=2]++; //why???
 }

    public static int[] getArray() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

In my opinion, to call the static method getArray it is necessary to write:

`getArray();` ... without the index!

I considered this code with a compiler error.

Can you explain me why `getArray() [index =2]++;` compiles without errors?

Comment: What compiler error did you expect from this code?

Comment: You'll get a `NullPointerException` when you run this, but I don't see any reason why it shouldn't compile.

Comment: The method returns an array.  The assignment returns an integer.  An array can be indexed by an integer.  The integer value at that index can be incremented.  What compiler error would you expect here and why?

Answer (score 3):

Let's go step by step:

- the method is supposed to return an array of int (`public static int[]`)
- that array gets then accessed at index 2 (`whateverArray [index=2]`)
- finally, the result of that access (an int value) can be incremented (`whateverArray[2]++`)
- and yes, a minor thing, you can assign a variable and use that as array index in the same statement, too

Thus this is all legal syntax. Of course, at runtime, you end up with a nullpointer exception.

The compiler could know that the method returns null, but standard javac does not care about such subtle details (for method results). And any decent IDE will tell you immediately that this code will break when executed.